# implicit retain inside block objective-c ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *friendsList;

// some method
...
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

_friendsList = [result objectForKey:@"data"];

}];
```

Is my code correct? I'm getting no warnings and code builds with no errors and all works just fine, but I wonder, if there are any hidden problems, such as implicit retain?

Comment: The point of properties is to use the setter/getter, accessing the ivar `_friendsList ` directly misses the whole point of properties. Instead use `self. friendsList`.

Comment: self.friendsList = ... means [self setFriendList:...] right? should I use weak self reference in this case?

Comment: Using `_friendsList` still uses self and does not avoid a retain. In your case the block is not externally retained by the class instance so there is no retain cycle. Where retain cycles are usually found is where the block is retained by a property and passed to a method and then inside the block a class instance is referenced.

Comment: Thank you, Zaph, for your answers!

Comment: If you don't get a warning, then you haven't turned on enough warnings in Xcode. You are living dangerous. @Zaph: The only difference between using the property and the instance variable is that assigning to the instance variable won't send notifications to any observers.

Comment: Essentially true. The other difference is a breakpoint can be set on a property and that requires the setter/getter to be called. There is method call overhead in calling the  setter/getter but that is not a good reason unless profiling points to it as a problem--that would be very unusual.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
_friendsList = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
```

means

```
 self->_friendsList = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
```

It line retains self, if it is not problem, then all fine. If it is problem you can use this:

```
__weak typeof(self) selfWeak = self;
FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
 __strong typeof(selfWeak) selfStrong = selfWeak;
if(selfStrong)
{
    selfStrong.friendsList = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
}
}];
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since the questions is asking if it is a problem. Also somewhat suggest the need for a weak self which is not needed since the block is not retain by the class instance.

Comment: Are you sure? The question: "Is my code correct?". In my answer:  "It line retains self, if it is not problem, then all fine."

Comment: You are not answering the question: "Is my code correct?". Adding the strong_self/weak_self dance when it is not needed is poor programming. Any code that is not needed is essentially incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. If retaining of self is not problem, then is not needed adding of self/ weak self dance. And I've indicated it: "If it is problem you can use this", I can show you example where it will be bad. For example: if self is UIViewController subclass with many components in memory, you can want to viewController has been destroyed as soon as possible, but network interaction will storing reference on ViewController. I don't know what is object self in this question, because I've added explanation for case, where it is bad. My be you know what class of self?

Comment: I can show many examples, where self retaining  is not good, but think more better create it in the chat.